# Approaching this.form from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with dealing with functions which calls `this.form`.

Here is that part of my source code:

```
searchResult.innerHTML += "<td><div class=\"searchcard\" draggable=\"true\" ondragstart=\"isexc=0; clickselect("
searchResult.innerHTML += i
searchResult.innerHTML += "); setformparam(this.form); onDragStart(event)\"
```

Here I tried to perform `setformparam(this.form)` when I start dragging `div` box constructed from within `innerHTML` script, but it doesn't work.

Any other function like `isexc=0, clickselect(i)` worked well.

Please teach me how to access `this.form` from within inner JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: Where do `setformparam()` and `clickselect()` come from? I have not seen those before.

Comment: @zero298 `setformparam()` and `clickselect()` are functions defined in same .js file with that source code. `setformparam(f)` calls form in html file, and saves certain informations to global variables declared in .js file.

Comment: @Teemu `searchResult` is a name of `div` included in the form in html file. It is located inside the '<form></form>' as `<div id="searchResult"></div>`

Comment: @fiverules `this` in your inlinehandler refers to `.searchcard` `div`. `div` is not a form element ([MDN: form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) ). I'd suggest you to use minitech's approach.

Answer (score 1):

That’s a terrible way of creating elements. Use the DOM:

```
var cell = document.createElement("td");
var searchCard = document.createElement("div");
searchCard.className = "searchcard";
searchCard.draggable = true;

(function(i) {
    searchCard.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
        isexc = 0;
        clickselect(i);
        setformparam(someForm);
        onDragStart(e);
    }, false);
})(i); // I’m just assuming `i` here is a loop variable of some kind
       // You should probably use Array.prototype.forEach

cell.appendChild(searchCard);
searchResult.appendChild(cell);
```

And use event delegation and stop using global variables. There are a ton of things to potentially clean up here, but you should probably try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it. But this is my first time to see DOM, so can you please give more explanation about what each line does?

Comment: @fiverules: HTML is parsed into a tree. Using `document.createElement` creates an element with the specified tag name that you can insert into that tree; `appendChild` does the actual insertion. `(function(i) { … })(i);` [is a wrapper that helps you with the closure-in-loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). If you don’t recognize the `addEventListener` method or function literal syntax, I’ll try to find a good up-to-date book on that, but those are need-to-know and hard to explain better than MDN does here.

Comment: Thanks. I got that it is a nicer way to create `searchcard` objects. But how can I access the `form` in the main html file from within?

Comment: @fiverules: Well, does it have an ID?

Comment: Oh, I got it. I made it by giving ID to each elements in `form` and call it by `document.getElementById`, rather than calling the `form` itself. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you are asking for, but if you want to get the form element as a DOM object, you can set an id to the element and call it by **getElementById**.

Or you can get it by **document.getElementsByTagName("form")[x]** where x is the index of the form you want.

Comment: What I want is to get the value of `checked` of radio button and `selectedIndex` of `select` inside the `form`. How can I do this?

Comment: Oh, I got it. I made it by giving ID to each elements in form and call it by document.getElementById, rather than calling the form itself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

try

`$(this).children('form')` and not `'this'`

Comment: That would be jQuery, which doesn’t appear to have anything to do with this.